# Rails 4: Why a helper included in a class is inherited but the instance method of a class is not

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have defined an instance method in models/item.rb (where someAmt is an attribute of Item) as such:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
class Item < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:8080/xxxx/"

  def displayInDollar(num)
    return "$#{number_with_precision(BigDecimal(num)/100,
      :precision => 2)}"
  end
end
```

and tried to use the method in index.html.erb like this (which does not work because the method is an instance method):

```
<tr>
  <td class="item_total">
    <%= @items.displayInDollar(BigDecimal(@items.sum(&:someAmt))/100, precision: 2) %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

However I am able to use the number_to_currency helper which I have included in the model item:

```
<tr>
  <td class="item_total">
    <%= @items.number_to_currency(BigDecimal(@items.sum(&:someAmt))/100, precision: 2) %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Is this because the NumberHelper has been automatically included, or why?

Comment: Do you really have include outside your class definition?

Comment: why `@items` (in plural)? Is it a single `Item` instance or a collection?

Comment: @BroiSatse i followed that somewhere..

Comment: @thaleshcv yea it's a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a lot of things which are wrong here. First of all, you execute `include` method outside of the class. That will result the module to be included within an `Object` class and hence will make all the methods available on pretty much every single object in your application. This is why you can use `@items.number_to_currency`. You also are able to use `nil.number_to_currency`, `15.5.number_to_currency`, `false.number_to_currency`. This is just wrong.

Now, even if you move it inside the class, it will still not work. `@items` is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relations` (most likely) or a collection of items. Your method is an instance method and can only be called on a single item.

That being said, this method should not even be an instance method of your Item, as this breaks MVC pattern. This method only purpose is to display given value in dollars, which is typical view concern. It doesn't even use any of the models attributes. It should be placed within helpers.